# objective-C variable layout

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, layout, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to investigate panic message I got that triggered from accessing address 0 in function `strlen` in my code, which is basically C++ with combined with objective-C variables.

The method that produce the panic doesn't access directly to `strlen` but from the ARC engine, and i'm trying to figure out what is `strlen` used for as part of autoreleasing the variable.

According to the next block copied from disassembler, it seems like the output of `[rax UTF8String]` produced null instead of valid string, and that's caused the crash eventually. Perhaps anyone can tell me what is the inner layout of objective-C that require this check after `autoreleasing` the variable.

```
*(int8_t *)(r15 + rbx) = 0x0;
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=(r13 + 0x198, &var_60);
rax = [var_98 orgName];
rax = [rax retain];
rax = objc_retainAutorelease(rax);
var_70 = rax;
r14 = [rax UTF8String];
var_90 = intrinsic_movaps(var_90, 0x0);
var_80 = 0x0;
r15 = strlen(r14);
if (r15 >= 0xfffffffffffffff0) goto loc_10001267b;
if (r15 < 0x17) {
        r12 = &var_8F;
        *(int8_t *)(r12 - 0x1) = r15 + r15;
        if (r15 != 0x0) {
                memcpy(r12, r14, r15);
        }
}
else {
        r12 = operator new(r15 + 0x10 & 0xfffffffffffffff0);
        var_80 = r12;
        var_90 = r15 + 0x10 & 0xfffffffffffffff0 | 0x1;
        memcpy(r12, r14, r15);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?
Which instruction do you not understand here?
Where is the original source code?

Comment: Hi, what i don't understand is why does the ARC take the return value of method `objc_retainAutorelease` convert it to `UTF8String`, check it's length using `strlen` and compare this value with the constand `0x17`.. I would expect that the ARC just release the variable and that's it ..

Comment: And you don't have the source? In the beginning of the code what is stored inside var_98, var_90, var_8F? I doubt that ARC does UTF8String/strlen. The ARC might insert objc_retainAutorelease, but the rest looks like a part of the program logic to me.

Answer (score 2):

ARC is only inserting `retain/release/autorelease` instructions. It will not insert anything like `UTF8String` or `strlen`.

[objc_retainAutorelease](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-runtime-objc-retainautorelease) is a combination of `retain` + `autorelease`. [autorelease](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571951-autorelease) operation is not releasing the value, it places an object into the current "autorelease pool" (it is like marking the object for future descruction).

In this code I assume that `orgName` returns an NSString into `rax`, then it converts this `NSString` to a C string by using `UTF8String` and places into `r14`. For some reason the author of this code decided (strangely enough) to not use `orgName.length`, but use `strlen` instead. So then the length of this string `orgName` is placed into `r15`.

If `orgName.length` (in `r15`) is less than 0x17, it copies the C string to `var_8F`.
Otherwise it allocates a new buffer `r12` and copies the `orgName` C string there.

Line `*(int8_t *)(r12 - 0x1) = r15 + r15;` is weird. It is like if var_8F had a byte-size field just before var_8F, and it puts a double of the string length there (the length is small, so it fits, but why double?).

Comment: Good analysis but the assembly is a little stranger, it does a `retain` and then a `retainAutorelease` (lines 4 & 5), which is a double retain... The `if (r15 >= 0xfffffffffffffff0)` is protecting the buffer allocation with `new` which rounds up the size to the next 16-byte boundary with `r15 + 0x10 & 0xfffffffffffffff0` (assuming strict left to right operations as would occur from sequential instructions).

Comment: I've noticed the double retain - strange indeed, but thought it's insignificant for understanding this piece.

Thanks for 0xfffffffffffffff0 explanation, now it makes sense, as I see that "+" is  calculated first, as in `(r15 + 0x10) & 0xfffffffffffffff0`.